# How do I use a dict to translate ArrayAgg values for an annotation in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django 4 with Postgres.

Say I have two related models like this:

```py
class Company(Model):
    ...

class Address(Model):
    city = CharField(...)
    companies = ManyToManyField(
        Company,
        through=ThroughCompanyAddress,
        related_name="addresses"
    )
    ...

class ThroughCompanyAddress(Model):
    company_id = ForeignKey(Company, ...)
    address_id = ForeignKey(Address, ...)
```

I want to annotate the cities that each company is in. Normally, I would do something like this:

```py
Company.objects.all().annotate(cities=ArrayAgg("addresses__city"))
```

Unfortunately, because of the way my DevOps team has the databases configured, these tables are stored on different databases, and I can't do this. Instead, I need to do 2 queries - first, to get a mapping of address ids to city names, and then to somehow use that mapping to annotate them onto the company models.

```py
# After the initial query to the first database, I end up with this
# Note: The int dict keys are the address model Primary Keys
cities = {1: "Paris", 2: "Dubai", 3: "Honk Kong"}

# Now how do I use this dict here?
(
    Company.objects.all()
    .annotate(
        city_ids=Subquery(  # Not tested, but I think something like this would work
            ThroughCompanyAddress.objects.filter(company_id=OuterRef("id")).values(
                "address_id"
            )
        )
    )
    .annotate(cities=???)
)
```

How do I use the `cities` dict in my annotation here to translate city_ids to city names?

I probably could do a Case/Where clause, but the `cities` dict can have dynamic data in it - it's not always going to have 3 items like above, so the clause would need to dynamically use the data in the dict somehow.

Or maybe I can't use a Case/Where, as my value is an array?